# Docker images lacking /tmp?

Tags: docker, debian, dockerfile

I was trying to build an image based on [this one](https://github.com/jj/rakudo-nostar), which is based on Debian Stretch, and kept getting this kind of errors when running `apt-get update`:

```
W: GPG error: http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.FNG6R8 for passing config to apt-key
```

This was fixed after just adding

```
mkdir /tmp && chmod 777 /tmp \
```

to the Dockerfile `RUN`. But then the question is, do Docker images lack the tmp file? Is that the case only for images based on `buildpack-deps:stretch-scm`? Is there a better way to deal with this than creating by hand a `/tmp` directory?

Comment: You're missing the sticky bit, you want /tmp to be 1777.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/tmp exists inside the image, your issue is elsewhere:

```
$ docker run -it --rm buildpack-deps:stretch-scm /bin/bash
root@c7fc40670734:/# ls -al /tmp
total 8
drwxrwxrwt 1 root root 4096 Nov 16 11:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Dec 27 19:48 ..
```

Note that /tmp should be set to 1777, not 777, you need the sticky bit for security

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error as you and as BMitch suggested,  adding this layer in my Dockerfile fixed it for me.

```
RUN chmod 1777 /tmp
```